# How to handle errors requiring program termination in Python functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `main()` function in my Python program which calls another function which in turn calls yet another function. There are certain conditions in those functions when the program has to call `sys.exit()`. One approach is to call the `sys.exit()` directly from the functions like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import logging
from git import Repo
from git import GitError


def git_clone(repo_url, repo_dir):

    try:
        Repo.clone_from(
            repo_url,
            repo_dir,
        )
    except GitError as err:
        logging.error(f'git clone failed: {err!r}')
        sys.exit(1)


def git(action, repo_url, repo_dir):

    if action not in ('clone', 'pull'):
        logging.error(f'git "{action}" is unknown action')
        sys.exit(1)

    if action == 'clone':

        git_clone(repo_url, repo_dir)


def main():

    git('clone', 'https://github.com/python/devguide.git', 'devguide')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        sys.exit(1)
```

An alternative approach would be to [raise](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise) an exception in functions and call the `sys.exit()` only in the main loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import logging
from git import Repo
from git import GitError


def git_clone(repo_url, repo_dir):

    try:
        Repo.clone_from(
            repo_url,
            repo_dir,
        )
    except GitError as err:
        raise GitError(f'git clone failed: {err!r}') from err


def git(action, repo_url, repo_dir):

    if action not in ('clone', 'pull'):
        raise ValueError(f'git "{action}" is unknown action')

    if action == 'clone':

        git_clone(repo_url, repo_dir)


def main():

    try:
        git('clone', 'https://github.com/python/devguide.git', 'devguide')
    except (ValueError, GitError) as err:
        logging.error(f'{err!r}')
        sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        sys.exit(1)
```

Which is the more pythonic, robust and maintainable approach? Or perhaps both are fine?

Comment: Are you seeking open-ended feedback on a program that achieves a specific task? If so, please retitle the question to state what that task is, as per the [ask] guidelines. Or are you asking about general principles of handling errors, with this code serving as a simplified, somewhat hypothetical, example? In that case, you're not really asking for a code review, and the question is out of scope for this site.

Comment: I raise that concern because the action is hard-coded to be `'clone'`, which makes it impossible to execute an unsupported action.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about general principles of handling errors based on the example in my original post. Sorry for the out of scope question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is definitely a place where reasonable people can disagree, especially for a CLI-like tool. I lean towards using exceptions, because they allow you to modify behavior at a top, centralized location. E.g., if you later want to support a "do this or, if it fails, do that", you can't if the "do this" calls `sys.exit()` when it fails.

The `click` CLI package uses a bit of a hybrid approach, using a "wrapper" like @K.H. mentions, `click.abort()`, to raise a pre-determined exception, `click.Abort`. This exception, in general, is something that only `click` should catch and handle (by exiting), but as a regular exception, it's also something you can catch and ignore if you want (or even adjust the error message at a higher level).

The only reason I can think of to use `sys.exit()` instead is to actively prevent higher levels of code from stopping the termination, but IMO that's a reason to use a very specific custom Exception type to discourage such behavior, not a reason to use `sys.exit()` any time you think you might be done running.

Comment: I would suggest `fire` over `click`, which requires way less configuration

Answer (score -1):

That really depends on you and how do you want your code to be used in the future.

- I would just exit right there if there is no question about it and you just want to exit.
- I would use exceptions and `sys.exit` in `except` only when I need to handle something more on the way, but I see it more error-prone as someone might forget to catch the right exception somewhere and your program would not exit when it should have. If this is supposed to be in your own module, it's fine. I wouldn't expect a library client to follow your rules.

Edit:
On the second thought, I would definitely extract the code, that initiates the `exit`. Then if you decide to change your logic, you can at least change this part in one place. I would suggest something like this:

```
def exit_with_message(message=None, code=1):
    if message:
        print(message)
    sys.exit(code)
```

Comment: Forcing the program to exit with `sys.exit` is not a good practice, as it prevents code from being reused. As @scnerd suggested I would rather use exceptions. This way, you can follow a "try-fail-try something else" approach